# Porque tendem os verbos, no presente do indicativo, a ser mais irregulares na 1ª pessoa do singular?

Tags: verbos, conjugações

Falo das irregularidades mais notórias na fala. Ignoro as variações meramente gráficas: *re**g**er, re**j**o*; *pade**c**er, pade**ç**o*, etc.. Ignoro também alternâncias entre ***a*** aberto e fechado, ***o*** pronunciado ***ó***, ***ô*** ou ***u***, ***e*** quase inaudível e aberto. Estas ocorrem também em palavras da mesma família: *ra**pa**z, ra**pa**ziada*; *ga**ro**to, ga**ro**tada*; *mu**lhe**r, mu**lhe**rio*, e tendem a ocorrer por razões meramente fonéticas, sobretudo a deslocação da sílaba tónica. Creio até que algumas destas alternâncias ocorrem só na pronúncia europeia e africana e não na brasileira

Agora na primeira pessoa do singular do presente do indicativo (e consequentemente em todas as pessoas do presente do subjuntivo) tendem a ocorrer com mais frequência do que nas outras flexões irregularidades mais pronunciadas: ***a*** que passa a ***ai***, mudança de consoante, ***e*** que passa a ***i***. Seguem-se exemplos, com as irregularidades assinaladas:

> Caber: **cai**bo, cabes, cabe, cabemos, cabeis, cabem.
>   Saber: **sai**bo, sabes, sabe, sabemos, sabeis, sabem (ter sabor).
>   Saber: **sei**, sabes, sabe, sabemos, sabeis, sabem (ter conhecimento).
>   Poder: po**sso**, podes, pode, podemos, podeis, podem.
>   Pedir: pe**ço**, pedes, pede, pedimos, pedis, pedem.
>   Ouvir: ou**ço**, ouves, ouve, ouvimos, ouvis, ouvem.
>   Fazer: fa**ço**, fazes, **faz**, fazemos, fazeis, fazem.
>   Trazer: tra**go**, trazes, **traz**, trazemos, trazeis, trazem.
>   Dizer: di**go**, dizes, **diz**, dizemos, dizeis, dizem.
>   Perder: per**co**, perdes, perde, perdemos, perdeis, perdem.
>   Valer: va**lho**, vales, vale, valemos, valeis, falem.
>   Sentir: **sin**to, sentes, sente, sentimos, sentis, sentem.
>   Mentir: **min**to, mentes, mente, mentimos, mentis, mentem.
>   Despir: **dis**po, despes, despe, despimos, despis, despem.
>   Vestir: **vis**to, vestes, veste, vestimos, vestis, vestem.

Não incluí verbos monossilábicos, que tendem a apresentar irregularidades em mais pessoas. Com uma sílaba só, não poderia ser de outro modo.

Estou em crer que há aqui uma tendência clara, e deve haver uma razão qualquer para ela. Qual é então a explicação desta maior frequência no presente do indicativo de irregularidades na primeira pessoa do singular?

Comment: O melhor artigo que eu encontrei (pois, em vinte minutos :) que explica tudo isso é
[*Regularidade e irregularidade nos paradigmas flexionais*](http://www4.crb.ucp.pt/biblioteca/Mathesis/Mat12/Mathesis12_89.pdf), por  Maria Luísa de Almeida. “Como se vê, *ouço, peço* e *meço* conservam até hoje a forma que
apresentavam no português medieval...”

Comment: Vou ler. Amanhã, ou isso. Entretanto, tenho esperança que alguém me escreva uma resposta... não mais longa que a mais longa das minhas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### English

Irregularities that are otherwise inexplicable if considered synchronically can sometimes fall into recognizable patterns if instead looked at diachronically. This is true for the verbs you mention. These are important irregulars to learn because it is the first person singular of the present indicative that supplies the stem for the present subjunctive.

Mostly what happened to almost all of these cases which you mention is that Latin had not a simple *-o* in the first person singular for these verbs, but *-eo* or *-io*.  The first of the two vowels became a semi-vowel /j/ and proceeded to change the previous consonant and sometimes even the preceding vowel.  There was no /j/ in the other persons, and so the second and third person singulars, plus the plurals, did not suffer its effects.

Take for example a verb like *dizer* which gives us both *digo* and *dizes*.  Latin had *dico, dices*; what happened to the *c* as the language evolved depended on the vowel following. Before /e, i/, it became /dz/ and finally /z/, but before /a, o, u/, it became voiced and therefore /g/.  This provides the alternation between /g/ and /z/ which we see in *digo, dizes* and *trago, trazes*.

Verbs that had *-eo* or *-io* in the first personal singular in Latin passed through an evolutionary period of the weak vowel becoming a semi-vowel, sometimes triggering palatalization on the previous consonant, and at other times causing metathesis. This occurred only in the first person singular, not in the the other persons, as they did not have the weak vowel to mutate.

So with *caber* from Latin *capere*, the first personal singular was *capio*, which became *cabjo* and then *caibo* under metathesis.  But *cabes* was under no such pressure. The same thing happened with *saber* from *sapere* by way of *sapio*.

With verbs like *valho, tenho, venho*, those started out as *valeo, teneo, venio* from *valere, tenere, venire*, and the weak vowel became a semi-vocalic /j/ before causing the previous /l/ or /n/ consonant to palatalize into /ʎ/ and /ɲ/. This pressure did not exist in the other persons.

With *faço, ouço, peço*, those were *facio, audio,* and a hypothesized **petio*. The /i/ became /j/, and so on from /dj/ and /tj/ to /dz/ and /ts/ where they were affricates, and finally modern /s/. Without the “yod”, the other persons did not suffer this.

In cases like *sinto, minto, durmo, visto* from *sentio, mentio, dormio, vestio*, this time the /j/ caused the /e/ and /o/ in the stem of the original to move higher in the mouth, to /i/ and /u/ respectively.

*Posso* is a more complicated case. The Latin had *possum* for the first person, but *potes* in the second and *potest* in the third. Different Romance languages developed different forms for this: where Italian has *io posso* but *tu puoi*, Spanish has *yo puedo* and *tu puedes* with the characteristic diphthongization in Castilian verbs in stressed position.

With *eu perco* (but *tu perdes*), it appears that in the transition to Vulgar Latin and Proto-Romance, there existed a **perdeo* form where Classical Latin had *perdo*. That should give rise not to *perco* but to *perço*, and I have not discovered what occurred in that case.

Although I understand why *saber* from *sapere* has two senses (to have flavor and to have acquaintance), I do not know why there are two first person forms in Portuguese; in Spanish they use *yo sé* for both senses of *saber*.

I am grateful for Maria Luísa de Almeida’s [Regularidade e irregularidade nos paradigmas flexionais‌​](http://www4.crb.ucp.pt/biblioteca/Mathesis/Mat12/Mathesis12_89.pdf) for many of these morphological insights.

### Português

<sup>*(O revisor assume a responsabilidade pelos erros de portugês.)*</sup>

Irregularidades que são de outro modo inexplicáveis se consideradas
sincronicamente, podem às vezes cair em padrões reconhecíveis
diacronicamente. Isto é verdade para os verbos que mencionaste.  Estas são
formas importantes a aprender, porque é a primeira pessoa do singular do
presente do indicativo que nos dá o presente do subjuntivo.

O que aconteceu com quase todos esses casos que
mencionaste foi principalmente que o latim não tinha um simples *-o* na primeira pessoa do singular para esses verbos, mas sim *-eo* ou *-io*. A primeira
das duas vogais tornou-se uma semi-vogal /j/ e começou a mudar a
consoante anterior e às vezes até mesmo a vogal anterior. Por falta de
/j/ nas outras pessoas, elas não sofreram esses efeitos.

Tomemos por exemplo um verbo como *dizer* que nos dá tanto *digo*
como *dizes*. O latim tinha *dico, dices*; o que aconteceu com
o *c* à medida que a linguagem evoluiu dependeu da vogal seguinte. Antes de
/e, i/, tornou-se /dz/ e, finalmente, /z/.  Mas antes de 
/a, o, u /, vocalizou-se e portanto tornou-se /g/. Isso fornece a alternância
entre /g/ e /z/ que vemos em *digo, dizes* e *trago, trazes*.

Os verbos que tinham *-eo* ou *-io* na primeira pessoa do singular passaram
por um período evolutivo da vogal fraca em que esta se tornou em semi-vogal, às
vezes provocando palatalização sobre a consoante anterior, e em outras
vezes causando metátese. Isso ocorreu apenas na primeira pessoa do singular
e não nas outras pessoas, já que estas não tinham a vogal fraca.

Assim em *caber* do latim *capere*, a primeira pessoa do singular
era *capio*, que se tornou /cabjo/ e depois *caibo*
por metátese. Mas *cabes* não estava sob tal pressão. A mesma
coisa aconteceu com *saber* de *sapere* por meio de *sapio*.

Verbos como *valho, tenho, venho* eram originalmente *valeo, teneo,
venio* de *valere, tenere, venire*, e a vogal fraca tornou-se uma semi-vogal
/j/ antes de causar a consoante anterior /l/ ou /n/  a palatalizar em /ʎ/ ou
/ɲ/. Esta pressão não existia nas outras pessoas.

*Faço, ouço, peço* eram *facio, audio* — e uma forma hipotética
**petio.* O /i/ tornou-se /j/, e assim /dj / e / tj / passaram a /dz/ e /ts/, tornando-se africados, e finalmente passaram ao nosso /s/ moderno. Sem o "yod",
as formas das outras pessoas não sofreram isso.

Nos casos como *sinto, minto, durmo, visto* de *sentio, mentio,
dormio, vestio*, desta vez o /j/ causou o /e/ e /o/
do original a subir na boca para /i/ e /u/ respectivamente.

*Posso* é um caso mais complicado. O latim teve *possum* na primeira pessoa, mas *potes* na segunda e *potest* na terceira.
Diferentes  línguas românicas desenvolveram diferentes formas para
isso: onde a italiana tem *io posso* mas *tu puoi*, o castelhano
tem *yo puedo* e *tu puedes* com a ditongação característica dos
verbos castelhanos na sílaba tónica.

Com *eu perco* (mas *tu perdes*), parece que na transição para
o latim vulgar e a língua proto-romance, existia uma forma **perdeo*
onde o latim clássico tinha *perdo*. Isso deveria dar origem a *perço*,
não a *perco*, e não descobri o que aconteceu nesse caso.

Embora entenda por que *saber* de *sapere* tem dois sentidos
(para ter sabor e ter conhecimento), não sei por que existem
duas formas distintas da primeira pessoa no português (os espanhóis 
usam *yo sé* para ambos sentidos).

Obtive muitas destas percepções sobre morfologia graças ao artigo de Maria Luísa
de Almeida, [Regularidade e irregularidade nsa paradigmas flexionais](http://www4.crb.ucp.pt/biblioteca/Mathesis/Mat12/Mathesis12_89.pdf)

Comment: Fantástico. Terei que ler de novo a uma hora mais acordada.

Comment: O que me espanta é que *au**d**es* (?) tenha passado a *ou**v**es*.

Comment: *Possum, potes* é complicado do ponto de vista das outras línguas românicas. O português ficou praticamente igual ao latim.

Comment: @Jacinto O italiano herdou *possiamo, possano* (ou seja *podemos, podem*) sem derivar novas formas a partir do infinitivo como parece ter ocorrido no português. Entendo a evolução *au**dio** > ou**ço***, mas não *au**d**is > ou**v**es*. O occitano medieval também tenha um *v* no seu *audire > auvir* onde a língua moderna tem *ausir*. Talvez o *v* será da forma do pretérito perfeito (*audi**v**i, audi**v**iste* no latim), mas não sei.

Comment: @Jacinto De [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-evolucao-historica-do-toponimo-provenca/24138): “«aparecimento da fricativa [V] para o lugar do que outrora tinha sido [D]» — [d] latino parece passar a [v], como mostra AUDIRE > **ouvir**; mas não se pode esquecer que a evolução não foi asim tão simples (o ✳ indica formas conjecturais e não atestadas): AUDIRE *✳odir > oir > ouir > ouvir* ” Então *o**u**ir* tornou-se *ou**v**ir* (por uma confusão do *V* por *U* na língua escrita??).

Comment: Não acredito que fosse via escrita. Quem é que sabia escrever nesses tempos? Mas não há uma via fonética para a passagem entre /v/, /w/ e /u/? Estou a pensar em palavras inglesas e alemãs com *wind, warm, wanderer, to warn/warnen, we/wir*.