# Por que razão ou razões é que a conjugação do verbo haver é tão irregular?

Tags: verbos

Se o verbo haver fosse regular a primeira pessoa do singular no presente do indicativo seria `eu havo`.

Em vez disso é

> eu hei

ou

> hei de

Isto tem alguma relação ao latim?

Comment: A maior parte da língua portuguesa tem relação com o Latim.

Comment: Há aqui [esta pergunta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/porque-tendem-os-verbos-no-presente-do-indicativo-a-ser-mais-irregulares-na-1%C2%AA) sobre várias irregularidades na conjugação de verbos, mas não cobre o verbo *haver*.

Comment: O _de_ em _hei-de_ não faz perto do verbo e escreve-se sem hífen com o acordo de 1990 (não obstante a unidade ter alguma coesão como em: _— Hás de cá vir. — Hei de, hei de..._).

Comment: @Artefacto *parte. De qual acordo estás a falar?

Comment: @nbro O acordo ortográfico de 1990: http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/about.html?action=vop-crit1

Answer (score 1):

O verbo haver vem do Latim *habere* que significa *ter*, sendo o verbo *ter* também irregular. Como outros disseram o *de* não faz parte do verbo. Tem [aqui](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?haber) mais explicações etimológicas.

### [Conjugação](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/verbos-portugueses/haver)

```
Eu hei
Tu hás
Ele/Ela há
Nós havemos ou hemos
Vós haveis ou heis
Eles hão
```

### O porquê da irregularidade

Em quase todas as línguas, os verbos usados amiúde, como haver, fazer, ver, ser ou ter, os mais comuns na utilização oral, mas também escrita, são irregulares. Tal sucede em quase todas as línguas latinas e nas línguas germânicas como em Inglês ou Alemão.

Tal é uma característica da comunicação e do desenvolvimento das línguas primitivas, pois as palavras usadas muito frequentemente, as que representam objetos e ações mais comuns, foram as primeiras a desenvolverem-se no processo antropológico de comunicação, e por conseguinte são simples e curtas (ter, ser, mão, pé, etc.). Sendo verbos curtos, pois os verbos que são usados amiúde devem ser curtos também por questões de síntese (*to be*, *to do*; *to see* em Inglês; *sein* em Alemão; *être* em Francês), ou seja com uma ou duas sílabas, a sua conjugação tende a ser irregular.

O verbo haver é ainda usado na língua Portuguesa como verbo auxiliar no pretérito mais-que-perfeito composto (como *havia dito*), e é usado na maioria das línguas Latinas como verbo auxiliar para o pretérito. Sendo assim um verbo que é usado amiúde, tende a ser um verbo curto; sendo um verbo cuja raiz é curta, é um verbo tendencialmente irregular.

Comment: Agradece-se, de acordo com as regras da casa, que antes de dar uma nota negativa, se apresente uma justificação nesta caixa de comentários.

Comment: Não percebo como é que a conjugação dos verbos pequenos tende a ser irregular *por eles serem pequenos*: `Sendo verbos curtos, (...) a sua conjugação tende a ser irregular.` e `sendo um verbo cuja raiz é curta, é um verbo tendencialmente irregular`. É uma observação do que simplesmente acontece, sem tentar explicar? Ou tem uma razão?

Comment: *ter* vem duma palavra mais grande, *tenere*, e, se não me engano, passou por *teer* (imagine *tẽ-er*) no caminho. Não foi inventado numa forma tão curta. E ambos *tenere* e *habere* são **regulares** no presente do indicativo: *habeo, habes, habet, habemus, habetis, habent*; *teneo, tenes, tenet, tenemus, tenetis, tenent*.

Comment: Experimentai, por recurso ao absurdo, imaginar que o verbo *ter* seria regular. Agora, aplicai a terminação de cada pessoa do singular, a *ter*, que se aplica aos verbos regulares terminados em *er*. Eu to / Tu tes / Ele te. A confusão seria enorme com outras palavras existentes e criaria entropia comunicacional. *Tenere* e *habere* são regulares porque, no meu entender, são verbos com três sílabas. Não sou linguista, sou engenheiro eletrotécnico com conhecimento de comunicação, por isso, aplico uma abordagem mais analítica da temática em questão e menos filológica.

Comment: @DanGetz, o processo de contração ou mesmo de eliminação de sílabas nas palavras de uma Língua, principalmente em palavras usadas amiúde em contexto oral, é comum. Hoje em dia há pessoas que dizem "tar" em vez de *estar*.

Comment: Obrigado; acho que entendo melhor agora, e concordo em geral.