# Por que "ouvir" apenas na primeira pessoa usa "ç"?

Tags: conjugações

O verbo "louvar" na primeira é "louvo", não "louço", isso faz sentido.

Entretanto "ouvir", apenas na primeira pessoa usa "ç", por quê?

Comment: Na primeira pessoa e no presente do subjuntivo (*que nos ouçam*).

Comment: Tens a resposta [aqui na resposta a esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/porque-tendem-os-verbos-no-presente-do-indicativo-a-ser-mais-irregulares-na-1%c2%aa/1526#1526). Vai lá e vê se ficas esclarecido.